# Panda dataFrame reshape generating NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I have the following code

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

file = open('path_to_a_json_file.json')
data = json.load(file)
df = json_normalize(data, 'keypoints', ['score'], record_prefix='keypoints_')
print df
df1 = df.reindex(columns=['score', 'keypoints_score', 'keypoints_position.x', 'keypoints_position.y'])
print df1
```

The `print df` generates the following output -

```
     keypoints_part                          keypoints_position  keypoints_score     score
0              nose  {u'y': 348.069222554, u'x': 503.185129916}         0.999788  0.922841
1           leftEye  {u'y': 304.606028353, u'x': 564.195195459}         0.999993  0.922841
2          rightEye   {u'y': 304.72363647, u'x': 471.077071629}         0.999861  0.922841
```

The `print df1` generates the following output -

```
         score  keypoints_score  keypoints_position.x  keypoints_position.y
0     0.922841         0.999788                   NaN                   NaN
1     0.922841         0.999993                   NaN                   NaN
2     0.922841         0.999861                   NaN                   NaN
3     0.922841         0.999759                   NaN                   NaN
```

I am not expecting the `NaN` ; how do i flatten the `keypoints_position` object ?

Comment: Is that a column of strings or objects? It'll change the answer a bit.

Comment: @cs95 keypoints_position column is of JSON objects.